# Audio conversion (LAME) C++ WAV -> MP3

Tags: c++, mp3, wav, lame

Good afternoon.
Sorry, I do not speak very good English.

For some days, I have tried to convert WAV to MP3.
For that I use LAME.
I can convert the file through the command prompt with the command:

```
lame.exe-B128 - resample 8-mj \ "C: \ \ test.wav \" \ "C: \ \ test.mp3 \"
```

but I'd like to not go through a command line (for portability across OSes), but I can’t do it in C++ (via the LAME library).

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
//...
//...
// extraction of PCM audio data file .wav in file.pcm
short read, write;

FILE *pcm = fopen("file.pcm", "rb");
FILE *mp3 = fopen("file.mp3", "wb");

const int PCM_SIZE = 18424;
const int MP3_SIZE = 13424;

short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE];
unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

lame_t lame = lame_init();

if ( lame == NULL ) {
    cout<<"Unable to initialize MP3"<<endl;
    return -1;
}

lame_set_num_channels(lame, 1);
lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 8000);
lame_set_out_samplerate(lame, 8000);
lame_set_brate(lame, 128);
lame_set_mode(lame, MONO);
lame_set_quality(lame, 2);
lame_set_bWriteVbrTag(lame, 0);
if (( lame_init_params(lame)) < 0) {
    cout << "Unable to initialize MP3 parameters"<<endl;
    return -1;
}

do {
    read = fread(pcm_buffer,sizeof(short), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
    if (read == 0)
        write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    else
        write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
} while (read != 0);

lame_close(lame);
fclose(mp3);
fclose(pcm);

return 0;
}
```

I get an MP3 file of very poor quality (and a shorter duration than the original).

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Here's my info.

```
Wav:
- Frequency= 8000
- BlocSize= 16
- Canal Nomber= 1 (mono)
- BytePerSec= 16000
- BytePerBloc= 2
- BitsPerSample= 16
- Bitrate= 128
- .wav size: 13466 (ie size of PCM: 13422)
```

Thank you.

Comment: A sample rate of 8000 Hz will never sound very good. I wish I could find documentation for the `brate` parameter, that might be key too.

Comment: @MarkRansom according to this code, it looks like 8kHz is also the input file's sample rate, therefore I'd tend to dismiss this parameter as the cause of the quality loss.

Answer (score 3):

```
 @try
 {
int read, write;
FILE *pcm = fopen([cafFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "rb");  //source
fseek(pcm, 4*1024, SEEK_CUR);                                   //skip file header

mp3 = fopen([mp3FilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "wb");  //output
const int PCM_SIZE = 8192*3;
const int MP3_SIZE = 8192*3;
short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

lame_t lame = lame_init();
lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 11025*2);
lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
lame_init_params(lame);

int nTotalRead=0;

do {
    read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);

    nTotalRead+=read*4;

    if (read == 0)
        write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    else
        write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame,pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    // write = lame_encode_buffer(lame, pcm_buffer,pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);

    fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
} while (read != 0);

lame_close(lame);
fclose(mp3);
fclose(pcm);
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
}
```